# Yii2 | requires bower-asset/jquery

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'm trying to install Yii2 via composer:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

~/.composer/composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.1.1"
    }
}
```

result:

```
Problem 1
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.x-dev requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 dev-master requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.5, 2.0.6, dev-master, 2.0.x-dev].
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 51):

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor
rm ~/.composer/composer.lock
cd ~/.composer
composer clear-cache
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.1.3"
composer install
```

Then go to your work directory and run:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic`

Comment: Very interestinmg.
I still have problems with this, but you pointed me to the rigth track. My problem was solved on local machine, but when I get to codeship it does not allow me to continue because it spects me to provide the gibhub token, and also wont allow me to run composer self-update.
Any Idea?

Comment: if you have old project instead of "composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic" just do "composer update"

Comment: This solution will not work with PHP 7.4 and Composer 2, it seems.

Answer (score 10):

You can try the newer version:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

then:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

---

#### Non-install Bower-Asset way:

You can download Yii2 by [Install from an Archive File](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/). By this way you won't need to handle Bower issue.

Further, if you need to update composer without handling Bower, you can require [yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip) before `yiisoft/yii2` in `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"
}
```

> Instead, if you want to create yii2 project without bower-asset issue:
>
> [yidas/yii2-app-basic](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-app-basic):
>
> `composer create-project yidas/yii2-app-basic`
>
> [yidas/yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-app-advanced):
>
> `composer create-project yidas/yii2-app-advanced`

---

> From Yii 2.0.13, it used Asset-Packagist solution instead of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`

Answer (score 7):

This problem could be also resolved via

```
composer require yidas/yii2-bower-asset
```

More details about this package: https://packagist.org/packages/yidas/yii2-bower-asset

Answer (score 1):

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
download and install. After installing run this command line in your project folder `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

First change the .composer permissions

```
sudo chown -R $USER .composer/
```

Then

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I needed to install the Composer Asset Plugin first:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
```