# composer install yii2-gii failed

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I am a new fish on `yii2`. I got a `yii2` code by `composer`,

and then found that there is not `yii2-gii`,

and then I added `"yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0"` to `require-dev` section in
 `composer.json`,

then `composer update` and an error occursed.

**Notice:**

- My OS is Windows 10.
- I have globally installed `fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.3` on my env.
- I tried this, [yii2-requires-bower-asset-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964462/yii2-requires-bower-asset-jquery),the same error info showed.
- I also tried globally installed `fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.1` instead of `~1.1.3` on my env,the same error info showed.

**Error Info:**

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable |
1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.14 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable |
1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.3 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable
| 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.13 requires bower-asset/jquery 3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable |
1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ~2.0.6 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

**My Question**

- How did this error occurs?
- What can I do to resolve this problem?

**APPEND**

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": {
        "packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.phpcomposer.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 | requires bower-asset/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964462/yii2-requires-bower-asset-jquery)

Comment: @Yupik  I have globally installed fxp/composer-asset-plugin:* on my env.

Comment: And that's your problem. Use version `1.1.3` as they described.

Comment: Yes ,I have tried it, and the same error info prompted.@Yupik

Comment: @Yupik Could you reproduce this?

Comment: try thaat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221864/vendor-folder-is-missing-in-yii2-and-composer-fails-update/51230865#51230865

Comment: @t6nnp6nn Actually, I except an explain of this problem rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've explicitly disabled `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`:

```
"fxp-asset": {
    "enabled": false
}
```

You should either change this to `true` or use [asset packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/) instead.

Comment: What error? If you explicitly disable plugin which provides `bower-asset/*` packages, then Composer is unable to find them.

Comment: I tried `asset packagist ` instead, and it worked for me. Thanks a lot.